# rails way to store assets of heroku app on amazon cloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services

Looking to have my rails app on heroku use amazon for everything is can (assets, database, uploads).

assets are bugging me the most...
Heroku help files say to create a bucket to dump files into and reference as: http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/filename.  This gives me two options for development (that I can think of):

1. I can have .gitignore not look at assets to develop locally and make sure I upload those files to my AWS bucket after scrubbing all my references or writing some helper?
2. Always store everything in my bucket and be forced to call my bucket during local development.

I'm wondering if it is possible for me to configure this so that locally I can store app assets in the app/assets folder and have it automagically push the assets over to amazon when pushing / deploying to heroku?

This is my first heroku rails app with amazon so feel free to insult my intelligence on how this stuff should be configured and the proper work flow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`asset_sync` gem](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync). This lets you do exactly what you want: use the asset pipeline locally, then serve assets from S3 (optionally via Cloudfront) after pushing to Heroku.

Note that Heroku's compilation step does not normally provide access to the configuration variables, and you need these configuration variables for `asset_sync` to push to S3. A solution for this (and in fact an entire asset_sync HOWTO) is posted in the [Using a CDN Asset Host with Rails 3.1](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31) guide.

The downside with this approach is that it violates some of the [12 factor app](http://www.12factor.net/) principles -- specifically having to do with "build, release, run". This has some negative consequences: for example, `heroku releases:rollback` will roll back your application but will *not* recompile and re-upload your assets.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3, you can use the [Rails assets pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to have different configuration for assets. Basically in your `config/environments/production.rb` file you do something like:

```
    ActionController::Base.asset_host = "/path/to/s3/bucket"
```

Locally, you will continue to serve the assets directly from the Rails server. Regarding deployment, you can write a rake task using the `aws-s3` gem or I think you should be able to automate this using `capistrano`. Another option is to use a CDN and configure it to search for assets on your production server so you don't need to deploy them separately.

Comment: At the moment I don't think I'm capable of writing a rake task or capistrano recipe to do this :(.  Thanks for the direction, the production.rb file edit will def help with my references and I'll do more research on the rake and capistrano.